# Merge several HTML to single HTML file

Tags: html, webpack

I'm creating a landing page, I use node, webpack.
And my landing HTML code becomes pretty long and hard to read. I want instead of this

```
index.html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="page1">...</div>
    <div id="page2">...</div>
  </body>
<html>
```

to have something like this:

```
index.html
<html>
  <body>...</body>
<html>

page1.html
<div id="page1">...</div>

page2.html
<div id="page2">...</div>
```

I know that I can achieve this with Vue or React but they seem to be excess for landing. Also seems webpack html loader can do this, but I not sure that it's a good idea to use JS just to insert HTML. Basically my question more about best practices - I can't find an answer either in google or in StackOverflow, so maybe I've chosen the wrong direction.

Comment: HTML itself does not have include options. https://css-tricks.com/the-simplest-ways-to-handle-html-includes/ And W3 offers JS solutions... https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Comment: Check for "ejs" library that is like jsx in "react" that will help you to code like components

Answer (score 0):

That in it self is not possible, BUT, you could use an iframe for all of the intended pages, like this:

```
<body>
<!-- Your code here... Styling also works... -->

    <iframe src="1.html" id="page1"></iframe>
    <iframe src="2.html" id="page2"></iframe

</body>
```